# Trouble scraping BBC with Python Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, typeerror

I am trying to scrape article headlines and summaries from the BBC science page, but keep getting a TypeError. Have tried to exception handle it with no luck.

My code is here:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class BBCScienceSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "bbc_science_spider"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science_and_environment'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):

        headline = response.xpath("//h3[contains(@class, 'gs-c-promo-heading')]/text()").extract()
        introduction = response.xpath("//p[contains(@class, 'gs-c-promo-summary')]/text()").extract()
        bbc_sci_dict[headline] = introduction


bbc_sci_dict = dict()

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(BBCScienceSpider)
process.start()
print(bbc_sci_dict)
```

The error I am getting is:

```
2020-08-23 23:03:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science_and_environment> (referer: None)
2020-08-23 23:03:20 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science_and_environment> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:/Users/tonyr/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 17, in parse
    bbc_sci_dict[headline] = introduction
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `extract` method returns a list. List are unhashable and therefore can not be used as keys of a dictionary.

```
    headline = response.xpath("//h3[contains(@class, 'gs-c-promo-heading')]/text()").extract()
    ...
    bbc_sci_dict[headline] = introduction
```

You either need to use `.get()` method instead of `.extract()`( this will return a string of the first item in the list) or choose an item of the list to assing as a key, like :

```
bbc_sci_dict[headline[0]] = introduction
```

Answer (score 0):

`extract()` returns a list. If your xpaths return a single match you can use `extract_first()` which will return the actual text of the first match.

```
def parse(self, response):

    headline = response.xpath("//h3[contains(@class, 'gs-c-promo-heading')]/text()").extract_first()
    introduction = response.xpath("//p[contains(@class, 'gs-c-promo-summary')]/text()").extract_first()
    bbc_sci_dict[headline] = introduction
```